# Return a Letter with Excel Function based on Another Value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a custom excel function that will return the corresponding letter if the target value is within the range.

Here's an example range:

```
Range
<=10      A
<20-<=35  C
<35-<=55  D
<55-<=80  E 
>80       F
```

So if the targeted value is 40 I want to the function to return the letter D. I already just use excel if then formulas to do this operation but would like to have a vba module that has the ranges stored.

Comment: I would approach that by using a case statement within the UDF. Have it return a value of type string. Just Google UDF Case Statement VBA and you will get some good help. :-).

Comment: You could do VLookup and Hide the table on another sheet, you could use arrays, you could use a really long `=IF()` formula, etc etc etc.  Hence my vote to close as TOO BROAD.

Comment: Thanks that's what I have been doing but it's used often and on different sheets so I'm looking for a way to make it universal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps you:

```
Option Explicit

Function ReturnLetter(number As Range) As String

Select Case number
    Case Is <= 10
        ReturnLetter = "A"
    Case Is <= 35
        ReturnLetter = "C"
    Case Is <= 55
        ReturnLetter = "D"
    Case Is <= 80
        ReturnLetter = "E"
    Case Else
        ReturnLetter = "F"
End Select

End Function
```

Put it in a code module and use it as a regular function on a worksheet.

Comment: Thank you! I'm very new to vba but I understand now.